# How to upload photos to facebook using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, facebook-graph-api

I am new to facebook integration and i am trying to upload photos to facebook from my application using javascript ,since 2 weeks  but i didn't find any solution upto now.I read facebook developers website but no use.i didn't find any proper answer related to javascript SDK.If any one can please convert the this PHP code in javascript or give me a proper guidance to upload photos to facebook???????????

The PHP code find here

```
https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/498/
```

i found below website doing this, i need like this in javascript?

```
    http://www.scrappur.com/
```

i registered to developers website and got APPID , SecretKey.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Facebook Graph API - upload photo using JavaScript](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/4999024/facebook-graph-api-upload-photo-using-javascript)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hurray........
I found solution,

```
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:fb="https://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
  <head>
    <title>My Feed Dialog Page</title>
    <g:javascript src="jquery1.7.1.js" />
  </head>
  <body>
  <div id='fb-root'></div>
    <script src='http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js'></script>
    <p id='msg'></p>
<script type="text/javascript">
$().ready(
            FB.init({appId: "you appId", status: true, cookie: true})
           );

    FB.login(function(response) {
       if (response.authResponse) {
         var access_token =   FB.getAuthResponse()['accessToken'];
         console.log('Access Token = '+ access_token);
         FB.api('me/photos', 'post', {
             message: 'has shared Picture http://www.scrappur.com/',
             status: 'success',
             access_token: access_token,
             url: 'http://www.maargasystems.com/images/gallery/thumbs/1.jpg' 
         }, function (response) {

             if (!response || response.error) {
                 alert('Error occured:' + response);
             } else {
                 alert('Post ID: ' + response.id);
             }

         });
       } else {
         console.log('User cancelled login or did not fully authorize.');
       }
     }, {scope: 'user_photos,photo_upload,publish_stream,offline_access'});


</script>

</body>
</html>
```